# AtTask API Named Search Queries

Tags: api, attask

I am building a reporting website against v4.0 of the AtTask API. It seems like none of the named queries off of projects is work.  For example:

```
https://foo.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/project/actualWork
```

By requesting this, I get the following JSON response:

```
{"error":{"class":"java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException","message":"APIModel V4_0 does not support namedQuery opTasks (PROJ)"}}
```

When I check the [API documentation](https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/api-explorer/) for v4.0, it has the Project object has an `Actual Work` named query.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I look at the document at https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/api-explorer/ I see the Section Project and there is no actualWork in that section, there is a actualWorkRequired.

There is a section Task and that has an option actualWork. Are you wanting to find the actual hours of a task? If that is the case the url would be

https://foo.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/task/actualWork

(There is also a section work that has a field actualWork)

let me know if that helps or if you have any other questions.